# Método que retorna a quantidade de objetos removidos de um array de objetos

Tags: java

O meu método realmente consegue remover os objetos do array, porém ele sempre retorna 0 a quantidade de removidos, já testei diferentes quantidades e ele sempre removia da lista, porém sempre retornava 0 de removidos. Gostaria que ele retornasse a quantidade correta de objetos removidos.

```
public int removerTodosClientesPorNome(String nome) {
    int quantidade = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < listaCliente.length; i++) {
        if (listaCliente[i] != null && listaCliente[i].getNome().equals(nome)) {
            listaCliente[i] = null;
            quantidade++;
        }
    }
    return quantidade;
}
```

Comment: Posta seu código completo.

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente ou seu método `getNome()` está retornando um valor diferente do pretendido ou o array está vazio ou o item que você pretende remover não está presente. Sem o código relacionado ao array não dá para avaliar precisamente.

O que pude fazer com esse fragmento de código que você publicou foi testar a lógica de execução, onde troquei o `array` por um `List<String>` e populei `listaCliente` com letras maiúsculas.

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;


public class HelloWorld
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    OtherClass myObject = new OtherClass();

    System.out.print("Foram removidos " + myObject.removerTodosClientesPorNome("J") + " itens.");
  }
}


public class OtherClass
{
  List<String> listaCliente = new ArrayList<String>();

  public OtherClass()
  {
    listaCliente.add("A"); listaCliente.add("B"); listaCliente.add("J");
    listaCliente.add("A"); listaCliente.add("B"); listaCliente.add("J");
    listaCliente.add("A"); listaCliente.add("B"); listaCliente.add("J");
  }


  public int removerTodosClientesPorNome(String nome) {
    int quantidade = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < listaCliente.size(); i++) {
        if (listaCliente.get(i) != null && listaCliente.get(i).equals(nome)) {
            listaCliente.set(i, null);
            quantidade++;
        }
    }
    return quantidade;
  }

}
```

---

cujo o resultado foi:

```
Foram removidos 3 itens.
```